# Show $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-1} E \left( \frac{1}{X}1_{[X>n^{-1}]} \right) =0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is a non-negative random variable satisfying 
\begin{align*}
P[0 \le X < \infty ]=1.
\end{align*}
Show

a)
 \begin{align*} \lim_{n \to \infty} n E \left( \frac{1}{X}1_{[X>n]} \right) =0 \end{align*}
b)

\begin{align*} \lim_{n \to \infty} n^{-1} E \left( \frac{1}{X}1_{[X>n^{-1}]} \right) =0 \end{align*}

**What I did**

I showed part a) already here is the proof:

\begin{align*}
n E \left( \frac{1}{X}1_{[X>n]} \right) \le n E \left( \frac{1}{n}1_{[X>n]} \right)=n\cdot\frac{1}{n}P[X>n]=P[X>n]
\end{align*}
So $\lim_{n \to \infty} n E \left( \frac{1}{X}1_{[X>n]} \right) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} P[X>n]=0$.

What about part b)? The same techniques no longer works.

I was thinking that 
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty} n E \left( \frac{1}{X}1_{[X>n]} \right) \le \lim_{n \to \infty} n E \left( \frac{1}{X} \right) \le 0
\end{align*}
but I am not sure that $E \left( \frac{1}{X} \right) < \infty$

Comment: Suspect the key here is that P[X<∞]=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was already asked on the site. Both results are consequences of Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.

Define $X_n=nX^{-1}\mathbf 1_{X\gt n}$ and $Y_n=(nX)^{-1}\mathbf 1_{nX\gt1}$, then $X_n\to0$ almost surely because $X$ is almost surely finite and $Y_n\to0$ almost surely because $Y_n\leqslant n^{-1}Z$ with $Z=X^{-1}\mathbf 1_{X\gt0}$ almost surely finite.

Thus, $E(X_n)\to0$ and $E(Y_n)\to0$ as soon as a domination condition holds. But it happens that...

> $$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad X_n\leqslant1\qquad Y_n\leqslant1$$

Comment: Could you please point to the link where it was done? Thanks a lot

Comment: If I had wanted to point to a duplicate, I would have done so and closed this question, instead of writing a full answer. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Actually on by side I can't see the answer. The gray bar doesn't show. Maybe its my PC. Thanks though

Comment: Did you try to place your pointer on the grey frame?

Comment: Thanks. I look at the Tex script. All clear now.