# Show that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {n^{ - 1}}E\left( {\frac{1}{X}{1_{[X > {n^{ - 1}}]}}} \right) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

I have to show that $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {n^{ - 1}}E\left( {\frac{1}{X}{1_{[X > {n^{ - 1}}]}}} \right) = 0$,  for X being a non-negative random variable satisfying $P[0 \le X \le \infty]=1$.

I try in this way, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we have:

$E\left( {\frac{1}{X}{1_{[X > {n^{ - 1}}]}}} \right) = E\left( {\frac{1}{{Xn}}{1_{[1 > \frac{1}{{nX}} > \varepsilon ,X > 0]}}} \right) + E\left( {\frac{1}{{Xn}}{1_{[\varepsilon  \ge \frac{1}{{nX}} > 0,X > 0]}}} \right)=A+B$.

So,

$A\le P[1 > \frac{1}{{nX}} > \varepsilon ,X > 0] \to 0$,

but, about B, I'm little confused, could someone help me?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1048545/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So $\dfrac{1}{n}1_{[X>1/n]}\rightarrow 0$ and that $\dfrac{1}{n}\dfrac{1}{X}1_{[X>1/n]}\leq 1$, Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem gives the result.

Comment: So, if $\dfrac{1}{n}\dfrac{1}{X}1_{[X>1/n]}\rightarrow 0$, and $|\dfrac{1}{n}\dfrac{1}{X}1_{[X>1/n]}| \le 1$, then I can apply DCT, rigth?

Comment: yes, but your assumption is that $X$ being nonnegative, so aboslute value is not needed.