# Durrett Ex.1.3.16

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X \ge 0$.  Show

\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to\infty} y\,\Bbb{E}\left[ \frac1X \cdot1_{X>y} \right] &= 0 \quad\text{and} \\
\lim_{y \downarrow 0} y\,\Bbb{E}\left[ \frac1X \cdot1_{X>y} \right] &= 0.
\end{align}

N.B.: The author *doesn't* assume $\Bbb{E}[1/X] < \infty$.

---

My try:

Since the expectation appears on the RHS of Markov's inequality, I *don't* think this inequality can be applied to solve this question.

$$
\begin{aligned}
y\,\Bbb{E}\left[ \frac1X \cdot1_{X>y} \right]
&= \Bbb{E}\left[ \frac{y}{X} \cdot1_{X>y} \right] \\
&< \Bbb{E}\left[ 1 \cdot1_{X>y} \right] \\
&= \Bbb{P}(X > y) \\
&\xrightarrow[y\to0]{} \Bbb{P}(X \ge 0) = 1
\end{aligned}
\tag1 \label1
$$

For the first part $y \to \infty$, I apply Markov's inequality at the row $\Bbb{P}(X > y)$ in \eqref{1}, so that
$$\Bbb{P}(X > y) \le \frac{\Bbb{E}[X]}{y} \xrightarrow[y\to\infty]{} 0?$$
But I *don't* have $\Bbb{E}[X] < \infty$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use $(1)$ to prove the first part or am I missing something? $$y \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{X} 1_{X>y} \right)  \leq \mathbb{P}(X>y) \xrightarrow[]{y \to \infty} 0.$$

Comment: @saz My concern is $\Bbb{P}(X = \infty) > 0$.  Say for any transient 1-D random walk, $S = \sum_n X_n$ drifts to $\pm\infty$ since $|E[X_i]| > 0$, so a random variable can be infinity.

Comment: Note that $$\mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{X} 1_{X>y} \right) = \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{X} 1_{X>y} 1_{X<\infty} \right)$$ as $\frac{1}{X}=0$ on $\{X=\infty\}$. If you follow your computations you then get $$y \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{X} 1_{X>y} \right) \leq \mathbb{P}(y<X<\infty).$$

Comment: @saz Thanks for your reply.  I'm thinking about the 2nd part.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1048545/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thanks for finding this out.  I remark that the linked question is more restrictive by assuming that $X$ is finite a.s., and its accepted solution uses LDCT, which can't be applied here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear from the comments that you already got the first part. The second part is even easier than the first part. One has for $y>0$:
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{y}{X}\mathbf{1}_{y<X} \right| \leq 1
\end{align}
Moreover:
\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{y}{X}\mathbf{1}_{y<X} = 0
\end{align}
By the Bounded Convergence Theorem:
\begin{align}
\lim_{y\to 0^+}\mathbb E\left[ \frac{y}{X}\mathbf{1}_{y<X} \right]=\mathbb E[0]=0
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer.