# Let $X$ be positive r.v. Prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} xE[X_{\left\{ X > x \right\}}^{-1}] = \lim_{x\downarrow 0} xE[X^{-1}1_{\left\{ X > x \right\}}]=0.$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

> Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable. Show that 
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to\infty} xE\left[X_{\{ X > x \}}^{-1}\right]
>  = \lim_{x\downarrow 0} xE\left[X^{-1}1_{\{ X > x \}}\right]
>  =0.
> $$

I was given the hint to not assume that $E[X^{-1}]<\infty$.

We replace $x$ by $n$ to make a sequence of random variables,
$\lim_{n\to\infty} nE[X_{\left\{ X > n \right\}}^{-1}]$, where our sequence is defined by $X_n=\frac{1}{X}1_{\left\{ X > n \right\}}$. Then, 
$X_n=\frac{1}{X}1_{\left\{ X > n \right\}} \to \emptyset$ as $n\to\infty$ almost surely.

But, I have that extra copy of $n$ in my problem. So, I should be defining my $X_n = \frac{n}{X}1_{\left\{ X > n \right\}}$, and I do not how to proceed.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1048545/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $$\left|x \cdot X^{-1} 1_{\{X>x\}}\right| = \left| \frac{x}{X} 1_{\{x/X<1\}} \right| \leq 1,$$

i.e. the constant function $1$ is an (integrable) dominating function for the expression on the left-hand side, uniformly for all $x$. On the other hand, it is not difficult to see that

$$x \cdot X^{-1} 1_{\{X>x\}} \xrightarrow[]{x \to 0} 0 \cdot X^{-1} 1_{\{X>0\}} = 0$$

and

$$ \left| x \cdot X^{-1} 1_{\{X>x\}} \right| \leq 1_{\{X>x\}} \xrightarrow[]{x \to \infty} 1_{\{X=\infty\}}.$$

Because of the dominating integrable function which we found at the beginning, this means that we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that

$$ \mathbb{E}(x X^{-1} 1_{\{X>x\}}) \xrightarrow[]{x \to 0} 0$$

and

$$\mathbb{E}(x X^{-1} 1_{\{X>x\}}) \xrightarrow[]{x \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(X=\infty)=0.$$