# Could any one tell me how to show the expectation is zero for this random variable?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Could anyone tell me how to show $$\lim_{y\to \infty}yE(\frac{1}{X}I_{X>y})=0$$ Given that $X\ge 0$ but $\frac{1}{X}$ may not be integrable. Thanks for the help. $I$ is an indicator function.

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1048545/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2948633/321264.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948633/let-x-be-positive-r-v-prove-lim-x-to-infty-xex-left-x-x-right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb E\left[\frac{1}{X}\boldsymbol 1_{X>y} \right]\leq \frac{1}{y}.$$

Comment: It ends the problem indeed !

Comment: $\mathbb E \left (\frac{1}{X} 1_{X>y} \right)= \int_{-\infty}^{y} \frac{1}{X}\times 0 dx+\int_{y}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{X}\times 1 dx$? am I right?

Comment: Could you be more detail please?

Comment: @MissQ: What you have written is wrong.  $$\frac{1}{X}\boldsymbol 1_{X>y}\leq \frac{1}{y}.$$ Therefore, taking the expectation both sides gives the wished result.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the question has been edited. Thanks for your further help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2948633/let-x-be-positive-r-v-prove-lim-x-to-infty-xex-left-x-x-right