# If $X\geq0$ is a random variable, show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1nE\left(\frac{1}{X}I\left\{X>\frac{1}{n}\right\}\right)=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expectation

> If $X\geq0$ is a random variable then show that:$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot E\bigg(\dfrac{1}{X}I\bigg\{X>\dfrac{1}{n}\bigg\}\bigg)=0$$

A hint would be most appreciated. I have studied measure theory, but I presume this can be solved using simple analysis.

Comment: Hint: This is $E(X_n)$ where $X_n=1_{nX\gt1}/(nX)$. What can one say about the pointwise limit of $X_n$ when $n\to\infty$? Are these random variables dominated by an integrable random variable? Ergo?

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n=\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{X}\mathbf{1}_{[X>\frac{1}{n}]}$. Show that $|X_n|<1$ and $X_n$ converges to $\mathbf{0}$. Then use Dominated Convergence Theorem..