# Lim of random variables

Tags: probability, limits, random-variables

> Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable such that $\mathbb P[X<\infty]=1$. Show that
>
> (i) $\lim_{n\to\infty} n\ \mathbb E\left[\frac1X\mathsf 1_{\{X>n\}}\right] = 0$;
>
> (ii) $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\ \mathbb E\left[\frac1X\mathsf 1_{\left\{X>\frac1n\right\}}\right]=0$.

I'm doing exercises of old exams of my course, but I'm not able to understand how to reason on this exercise, can someone help me?

I did what a random variable is, the measurability,, the measure induced on the real line. I know that $\mathbb P[X<x] = F(x)$. I also know limit's properties and the definition of continuity

Comment: What have you tried so far? People will be more receptive to helping you if you can show why you are stuck. If you truly cannot get started, then listing some techniques you have learnt about for similar questions can help people write their answer at the right knowledge level so you understand it

Comment: I did what a random variable is, the measurability,, the measure induced on the real line. I know that P[X<x] = F(x). I also know limit's properties and the definition of continuity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convergence of $E(X_n)$ where $X_n=\frac nY 1_{\{Y&gt;n\}}$ for any non-negative rv $Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162951/convergence-of-ex-n-where-x-n-frac-ny-1-yn-for-any-non-negative-rv)

Comment: Second question is answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162903/321264.