# Equations that may relate to monotone convergence theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I want to show the following equations, assuming that $X$ is a non-negative random variable.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} n E(\frac{1}{X}I_{\{X>n\}}) = 0$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}E(\frac{1}{X}I_{\{X > \frac{1}{n}\}}) = 0$

I think they may be related to the monotone convergence theorem, but I have no clue how to approach them. Any hints?

Comment: Do the functions $\frac nX I_{X >n}$ and $\frac 1{nX} I_{X > \frac 1n}$ behave monotonically? If you check this then you can see if MCT applies or not.

Comment: I noticed that $\frac{1}{x}I_{X>n}$ is monotone decreasing to 0, is that why the first equation is true?

Comment: Yes, but note that the monotone convergence theorem is usually stated for monotone increasing functions, so can you modify what you have, to use this result and make things work?

Comment: The first one is easy: $\frac  n X I_{X>n} \leq I_{X>n} $ and $P(X>n) \to 0$.

Comment: by the same reasoning, $\frac{I_{x >\frac{1}{n}}}{nX} < I_{x > 1/n}$?

Comment: The second one follows by DCT: $E(\frac 1  {nX} I_{nX >1}) \to 0$ since $\frac 1 {nX} \to 0$ a.s. and we have domination by the constant $1$.

Comment: Answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/162951/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1162903/321264.